# Issues Creating Image Sequence Animation in IE11

Tags: javascript, css, image, internet-explorer, skrollr

I'm using Skrollr.js to animate an image sequence.  I took inspiration from how the http://moto.oakley.com site handles image sequences, and built some scripts to help me automate writing a series of images into the DOM.  Then, I use Skrollr to change the `display:none;` to `display:block` at key scroll positions.  My script preloads all the images before dispatching a complete event, and then I initialize Skrollr and allow interaction.

So, basically I have a `<div>` containing that has a bunch of these:

```
<img src="seq-000.png" data-0-top="display:block;" data-50-top="display:none;">
<img src="seq-001.png" data-0-top="display:none;" data-50-top="display:block;" data-100-top="display:none;">
<img src="seq-002.png" data-50-top="display:none;" data-100-top="display:block;" data-150-top="display:none;">
...
```

Now, this is working just fine in Chrome and FireFox (naturally), but Internet Explorer 11 seems to have problems rendering the images during the first scroll through the page.  In other words, when I first load the page and scroll the images blink into place like they have not be preloaded, but subsequent scrolls the animation is perfectly fine.  It's like IE11 hasn't rendered the images into memory, so the draw speed to the screen has a delay the first time any image is displayed.

I don't think Skrollr is the problem.  Perhaps there's some magic CSS setting I should using.

Does anybody have any tips for making image sequences so they look ultra smooth everytime even in Internet Explorer?!?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey - ever found a solution about this ? same issue here...

Comment: No, unfortunately.  The project was canned, so I never got to a final Q&A stage where I had to find a solution.  Interestingly, I've used this plugin which seems to handle images sequences by updating the src.  It's always worked great in IE11, so maybe it's worth inspecting the code and take inspiration from that. [jQuery Reel Plugin](http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel).

Additionally, the last scrolling site I worked on we switched to [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/).  I get much more control with that library.

Sorry, I can't be of more help.  Good luck!

Comment: That's nice from you to answer 2 years after :-). Thanks I'll dig into those libs.